# How to set the path to the latest Open MPI version?

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables, paths

I'm using Ubuntu **14.04** and the installed Open MPI is **1.6.5**; I've installed the Latest Open MPI[(**4.0.0**)](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.0/) following these instructions [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building) and set the installed location by-

```
./configure --prefix=/$HOME/Downloads/openmpi
```

Then, to set the path I've added these lines to my `.bash_aliases` file-

```
om() {
    export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/bin
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/lib
}
```

I've run the `om` command and then ran `mpirun --version` but it still outputs-

```
mpirun (Open MPI) 1.6.5

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

How can I keep and use both the Open MPI versions?
Thank you.

Comment: `PATH` is searched in order: if you want the new version to be found *first*, you will need to prepend rather than append the location i.e. `export PATH=$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Yes, that worked. You should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning the comment into an answer:*

The `PATH` environment variable is traversed in order from front to back. The old MPI version is found because it is positioned *before* the path to the new version in your `PATH`. If you want to find the **new** MPI version first, you should *prepend* its path in the `PATH` variable:

```
om() {
    export PATH=$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/bin:$PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Downloads/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
}
```